# Join on everything else value if not in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, join

I have a dimensions table

```
@dimensions
Dateid  Rep Mkt Prodgroup
201111  002 S   001
201111  002 R   001
201111  002 S   002
201111  002 R   002
201111  002 S   003
201111  002 R   003
201111  002 S   004
201111  002 R   004
...
```

I want to join it with this table to include the percentage.

```
@percentageincrease
Prodgroup   Mkt Percent
ALL         S   1.05
ALL         R   1.06
002         S   1.07
002         R   1.08
003         S   1.09
003         R   1.10
```

I want to join them on `Mkt` and `Prodgroup` where `@dimensions.Prodgroup IN @percentageincrease.Prodgroup` and if `not in` then to join on the ALL. So the output table would be

```
Dateid  Rep Mkt Prodgroup   Percent
201111  002 S   001         1.05 // joined on ALL
201111  002 R   001         1.06 // joined on ALL
201111  002 S   002         1.07 // joined on 002
201111  002 R   002         1.08 // joined on 002
201111  002 S   003         1.09 // joined on 003
201111  002 R   003         1.10 // joined on 003
201111  002 S   004         1.05 // joined on ALL
201111  002 R   004         1.06 // joined on ALL
...
```

As my join condition I have tried

```
on case p.Prodgroup 
    when N'ALL' 
    then d.prodgrpid 
    else p.Prodgrpid = d.prodgrpid
AND p.Mkt = d.Mkt
```

but it gave me

```
Dateid  Rep Mkt Prodgroup   Percent
201111  002 S   001         1.05
201111  002 R   001         1.06
201111  002 S   002         1.07
201111  002 R   002         1.08
201111  002 S   002         1.05 //Joined on ALL
201111  002 R   002         1.06 //Joined on ALL
201111  002 S   003         1.09
201111  002 R   003         1.10
201111  002 S   003         1.05 //Joined on ALL
201111  002 R   003         1.06 //Joined on ALL
201111  002 S   004         1.05
201111  002 R   004         1.06
...
```

where the tuples which were in the @percentageincrease table were also joined on the ALL condition.

This is being run on SQL Server 2008 as a stored procedure as part of a larger query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table structures

```
declare @dimensions table 
    (Dateid varchar(10),  Rep varchar(10), Mkt varchar(10),Prodgroup varchar(10))
declare @percentageincrease table 
    (Prodgroup varchar(10),  Mkt varchar(10), [Percent] decimal(9,5))
```

then

```
select 
     d.*, 
     isnull(pinc.[Percent], pincall.[Percent]) 
from @dimensions d
    left join @percentageincrease pinc 
        on d.Mkt = pinc.Mkt
      and d.Prodgroup = pinc.Prodgroup
    left join @percentageincrease pincall
        on d.Mkt = pincall.Mkt
      and pincall.Prodgroup ='all'
```

Comment: I tested your query at sqlfiddle and see the result. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7aa65/1 by the way don't forget to convert the data type of `Prodgroup`

Comment: You have prodgroup as an int - so the join doesn't work. From the above sample data it appears to be a string.

Comment: did you try to click the link? see the values for the `percent`

Comment: @JohnWoo Yes. Try it with the table structures in my answer.

Comment: Thanks heaps. That worked perfectly. I simplified my example slightly for SO as I was actually modifying an existing join (@dimensions) to add on the percentage increases but this example applied in both situations.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * from 
(
select d.*,p.[Percent] from 
dimensions d inner join percentageincrease p
on d.Mkt = p.Mkt  and d.Prodgroup = p.Prodgroup 

union 

select d.*,p.[Percent] from 
dimensions d  join percentageincrease p
on d.Mkt = p.Mkt  and d.Prodgroup not in
  (select distinct d.Prodgroup  from  dimensions d inner join percentageincrease p
   on d.Mkt = p.Mkt  and d.Prodgroup = p.Prodgroup) 
  where p.Prodgroup='ALL'  
) a
order by a.Prodgroup
```